# Pattern based string parsing

Tags: c#, string-parsing

I have below string as input

```
string input = "{A.0a,100,0002_VL}{=}{A.0a,0400,0001_VL}{+}{A.0a,0410,0002_VL}{+}{A.0a,0420,0003_VL}"
```

I want below output as string array

```
string[] output 

output[0] = "A.0a,100,0002_VL"
output[1] = "="
output[2] = "A.0a,0400,0001_VL"
output[3] = "+"
output[4] = "A.0a,0410,0002_VL"
output[5] = "+"
output[6] = "A.0a,0420,0003_VL"
```

I want to use RegEx.Split function but unable to identity a pattern. Is it possible to use? Kindly help me.

Comment: `output = input.Split(['{', '}'], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptryEntries)`?

Comment: Try the pattern `[{}]+`?

Comment: Hi Juharr,  string[] output= Regex.Split(input, "[{}]+"); also worked. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char[] charArray = { '{', '}' };
    
var inputArray = input.Split( charArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Wow that is simplest solution. It worked. Thank you so much.